# Word for the superset of files and folders

Tags: naming

I'm trying to come up with a name for a class that can represent both files and folders. Anyone know a word for this?

Comment: I think this has been asked before but I can't seem to find it... I'd suggest "Filesystem Object".

Comment: FileSystem node?

Comment: If you are developing in the Windows environment, I would not recommend "Filesystem Object", since this has already a different meaning (it means a special COM object provided by Microsoft as part of the Scripting Runtime library, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Folder entry? http://www.ntfs.com/fat-folder-structure.htm

Comment: If you google "folder" and "file" you get back the same image results (so they share similar meaning), which makes me think that you can just call both files and folders "file" just like linux does it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider `FileNode` or `FileSystemNode`.

I've used `FileNode` in previous projects, the other devs were able to guess what it did from the name.  The `-Node` part lets others know you're working with a tree.

Comment: I prefer `FileSystemNode`, as `FileNode` sounds like it might be specific to files.

Answer (score 4):

As everything (except the root folder or root of a drive) is ultimately contained within a folder, you could just go for `FolderElement`, although `FilesystemObject` (as suggested by @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner in a comment) also sounds good.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the operating system and the file system. On Unix, a directory is just a special file, so the correct term would be *file*.

NTFS has a similar unifying concept, albeit much more complex than on Unix, called *attribute*.

Comment: Although technically correct, I feel that most people would assume a class "file" is associated with documents, not folders.

Comment: Documents are yet another can of worms entirely. A single document may be split across multiple files and a single file may contain multiple documents.

Comment: I don't know what to call anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call you class "FilesAndFolders" or do you have a character-limit for naming?
Well I guess you could call all of them entities, so: "FileSystemEntity"